# How to test if a transaction is standard without spending real money?

Tags: testnet, non-standard-transaction

The problem with Testnet is all types of transactions are allowed, so how can I know if a transaction would be rejected on mainet ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use Bitcoin Core's `testmempoolaccept` RPC. It will tell you whether the transaction you give it would be accepted into your node's mempool at that time but won't actually add it to the mempool or broadcast it.

Comment: But then the question is how to convert a transaction to a full raw hex transaction ?

Comment: @user2284570 In what format do you have the transaction, if not raw hex?

Comment: @PieterWuille I have it in partial hex. I mean I have only the output in hex which means I would have expected something which would take the TxOut hex and the private key for automatically selecting utxo and perform signing.

Comment: You can create a transaction with no inputs using `createrawtransaction`, add inputs to it using `fundrawtransaction`, and then sign it with `signrawtransactionwithwallet` or `signrawtransactionwithkey`.